# What's the difference between Initialization and Assignment in C#

Tags: c#, initialization, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# variable initializations vs assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779707/c-variable-initializations-vs-assignment)

Just like in the title, could someone please explain what is the difference between Initialization and Assignment in C#? I'm preparing for a test and I wanted to know what's the best way to answer this type of question. Thanks

Cheers,
n1te

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you initialize a variable you're declaring it into existence.

```
PlasticCup mySippyCup = new PlasticCup();
```

When you assign, you're just saying "this water" goes into "this cup". The cup already exists.

```
mySippyCup = new PlasticCup();
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialization is *assigning* value while declaring the variable - `int a = 1`

Assignment is just assigning value to a variable - `a = 1`

By this definition, some say all initializations are assignments, but all assignments are not initializations.

Comment: Given your example:
int a //declaration,
a = 1 //initialization,
a = 2 //assignment. Why are those 3 steps required, why not just declare and assign a variable and skip initialization?