# How to declare at beginning of program

Tags: c, initialization, global, global-scope

In the listing below, an attempt to declare the rectangle **"r" before the main()** function is called results in an error.

> ```
> error: 'r' does not name a type r.x = 150;<br>
> ```

Why must "r" be declared after main()?

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    // Creat a rect at pos ( 50, 50 ) that's 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels high.
    SDL_Rect r;
    r.x = 150;
    r.y = 150;
    r.w = 200;
    r.h = 100;

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow   ("SDL2 rectangle", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                 SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                 640,
                                 480,
                                 SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );

    // Setup renderer
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    renderer =  SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 ); // black background
    SDL_RenderClear( renderer );    // Clear winow
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0, 255, 255, 255 ); // rgba drawing color

    // Render rect
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &r );

    // Render the rect to the screen
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    // Wait for 5 sec
    SDL_Delay( 5000 );

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You mean, as a global variable rather than as a local one?

Comment: You should be able to have `SDL_Rect r` as a global variable before `main`, but not the assignments. `r.x = 150;` and co. must be in a function.

Comment: Also, this might work as a global variable: `SDL_Rect r = {150, 150, 200, 100};`

Comment: As this is completely unrelated to SDL I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> r.x = 150;
> ```

This is not a declaration, nor a definition, but an assignment.

C does not allow assignments on global level.

You still could define a variable at global scope

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

SDL_Rect r;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
```

Every variable *defined globally* undergoes a default initialisation:

- integers variables are set to `0`.
- floating point variables are set to `0.`.
- pointer variables are set to `NULL`.

Even more you could also initialise it explicitly

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

SDL_Rect r = {1, 2, 3, 4};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
```

Although an initialisation looks similar to an assignment it is not the same (as you already observed).

[More on the difference between assignment and initialisation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674396/694576)

Comment: The SDL_Rect r = {1, 2, 3, 4}; does work. I dont understand why *"C does not allow assignments on global level"*, so I will get a good book and read it. I am use to PHP allowing me to do what ever I want, where ever I want :( Thankyou

Comment: @jwzumwalt: "*I dont understand why 'C does not allow assignments on global level'*" that's just you how the language is defined/designed.