# Proper way to assign single value to multiple variables

Tags: c

I'm studying C programming ( with codeblocks IDE ) and I want to ask the following question :

Why is it wrong to write

```
int "i=j=0;"
```

rather than

```
"int i,j;

i=j=0;" or "int i=0,j=0;"
```

Comment: variables need to be declared. `int i = j = 0; /* what is j? */`

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you never declare `j`. Either of the other two versions are fine as far as the C syntax goes.

However, it is considered good style (and this is subjective) to always declare every variable on a line of its own, and to never use multiple assignments in the same expression. Therefore I would personally recommend to do this instead:

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
```

Comment: In order to give more details, `=` operator in C have a right-to-left associativity, which means that `int i = j = 0;` is equivalent to `int i = (j = 0);`. Looking things that way shows that this line use but don't declare the variable `j`

Comment: @DrosvarG One problem is that the = has no specified order of evaluation though, regardless of associativity. Which is one reason why it is better not to chain multiple = on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

The names need to be known before you can assign to them. Therefore, this is the closest thing to what you're looking to do:

```
int j;
int i = j = 1; /* OK, j is known */
```

When it comes to best practice, it's better to have them on separate lines as shown in Lundin's answer.

Comment: There's actually a difference between `int i=0; int j=0;` and `int i; int j; i = j = 0;`  In the first, both variables are *initialized* to zero.  In the second, `0` is *assigned* to both variables.  [They're not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662831/initialization-vs-assignment-in-c), especially for complex types.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t have declared `j`, so you will get an error because of an undeclared variable.
A better way is to declare an variable in the following way:

```
int a, b;
```

Or if you want to set also the value:

```
int a, b = 1;
int a = 1, b = 1;
```