# Question about "int". Integer vs Initialize in C

Tags: c, integer, initialization, cs50

I am confused about how to distinguish the use of "int" when declaring something an integer versus using it to initialize a variable.

In the following example I believe I am initializing the variables n,m,y:

```
int main(void)
    {
    int n,m,y ;
}
```

How can I tell between "integer" and "initialize"

Thank you

Comment: *"I believe I am initializing the variables n,m,y"* - so, to which value are you initializing them? Think about it.

Comment: `n,m,y` in your example is declared locally and not marked as `static`, so they have *automatic storage duration* and are not initialized.

Comment: You are *declaring* three integer variables but not initializing them. But I'm not entirely clear about what you are asking, in terms of the use of the "int" term.

Comment: Initializing is `int n = 0;`  It is also a declaration and the first assignment.  Get into the habit of declaring your variables on individual lines, one variable per line.

Comment: Do you mean the difference between `int x` and `int x = N`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Technically (I think) [initialization is not assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35662831/10871073).

Comment: @AdrianMole: Initialization is the *first* assignment, in this case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's a bit nitpicking, but an initialization is technically not an assignment. The rules for assignment and initialization varies.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not something worth getting into an argument about, but there are some subtle differences (IIRC) in terms of what compilers are allowed to do with initializations versus assignments.

Comment: Does it have any relevance to the code in the OP?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Depends, but now when we have argued about it I think it's clear to OP :)

Answer (score 3):

```
int foobar; //this is a declaration of an integer variable 

foobar = 42; // this is assignment of the variable 

int x = 52; // this is declaration and initialization in one line so you perform two things in this line: declaration and initialization to value 52
```

Comment: Oh well, yes you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no distinction to be done here.

You have two mention of `int` in your code.

`int main(...` indicate that you have a main fonction whose return value is an integer.

`int n, m, y;` indicate that you have created 3 integer variables named n, m and y.

None of these 3 variables are initialized as you didn't set a value for any of those.

`int n = 0, m = 1, y = 3` here we have three initialized integer variables. n initialized to 0, m initialized to 1 and y initialized to 3.