# Why do we need to specify the data type of variable before assigning a value?

Tags: c

Let’s say we want to define a variable that stores the age of a certain individual;

```
int main(void) {
 int age=5;
 printf(“%d\n”,age);
}
```

Here, before assigning the variable, we specify the type of data it would store. Does we define it just to tell the compiler/interpreter how many bytes the value will occupy in memory. No other reason?

Comment: This is just the way C works. Maybe you're from a background in a different language, like Python, where the type of the variable is deduced from what it's given; but that's not what C does.

Comment: A simple `age = 5` line could be expecting `age` to be `int`, `long int`, `short int`, `unsigned int`, or even `char`, `float` or `double`.

Comment: Just suppose the compiler were to automatically give a type `char` to the untyped `a = 5` on the grounds that this is a large enough integer type able to hold the value. Later in the program you try to assign `a = 500` but that will fail because the type isn't big enough.

Comment: Without specifying the type, how will you know to use `%d` in `printf()`?

Comment: Because the language demands it. Because C isn't Java Script. Because programming languages are like very restrictive natural language. They have rules. they have syntax. Natural languages are fairly translucent in that their meaning is frequently conveyed by inference. Ex: you could tell your friend "I'm going to the store.", "Going to the store", "Going... store", and even just grunt "Store", and your friend will *probably* be able to infer your intent from all of the above. Most programming languages are inference deficient (they have none). So we must tell it. C is one such language.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662831/initialization-vs-assignment-in-c

Comment: @hyde I don’t know how are they related.

Comment: @VinaySharma The assignment you show is special, because it has an *initializer*. It's not a normal case of assigning a value.

Comment: In fact, it's not an assignment at all.  Although they both use the the `=` symbol, initialization follows different rules than assignment.

Comment: Worth noting that a language without `var`, `auto`, `dim`, keyword at the very least, runs into the php/python problem where you need an extra `global` keyword in case you want to use global variables(and many c programs use global variables since they do not need to be initialized at runtime, as they are part of the program image, or just do not want to deal with passing state around). If I am not mistaken, C moved away from `auto`, which B language used, as it wanted types to not all be the same size.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think in C that actually is/contains an _assignment-expression_.  C++ is different, probably, not 100% sure. I mean, if talking with technical terms and looking at language spec and the terms used there.

Comment: @hyde, the only thing I can imagine you mean is that the C formal grammar for an `initializer` includes the `assignment-expression` symbol as one of its alternatives.  But that symbol represents not an expression involving the `=` operator, but rather an expression can appear *as the right-hand operand* of an `=` operator.  In no way does that imply that initialization is assignment, even before we consider the other alternatives for initializers that are not `assignment-expression`s.

Answer (score 1):

Variables usually change their value (that's why they are called variables). The initial value of a variable usually doesn't say much about how the variable is used, and what it's for.

If you want to implement an algorithm which calculates an average age, you might need your variable which holds the age to be non-integer, like `float` or `double`. You usually want to initialize it to 0, which is an integer, so the compiler can't come up with a correct suggestion for its type.

```
int main(void)
{
    int age=5;
    printf("%d\n",age);
    // Now print the age in decades (units of 10 years)
    printf("%d\n", age / 10); // prints 0 - incorrect answer

    double correct_age = 5;
    printf("%f\n", correct_age);
    // Now print the age in decades (units of 10 years)
    printf("%f\n", correct_age / 10); // prints 0.5 - correct answer
}
```

---

C++ has support for type inference: `auto age = 5` declares age as an integer, while `auto age = 5.0` declares it as `double`. This support was not deemed important when C was created, and it's still not as important in C as in C++, because in C++ types sometimes have long names.

Answer (score 1):

> Here, before assigning the variable, we specify the type of data it would store.

No, that's a mischaracterization.  You present a *declaration* of variable `age` that happens to include an initialization.  Initialization is not assignment.  Although in many cases you could separate that into a declaration without initialization and a separate assignment, there are cases where that would not be valid.  Overall, the declaration is the primary element in the code presented, not the initialization.

> Does we define it just to tell the compiler/interpreter how many bytes the value will occupy in memory. No other reason?

We specify the data type because modern C requires variables to be declared before use, and the data type is a required part of the C syntax for variable declarations.  At the language level, that's why, end of story.

As for what benefits that yields, yes, it does convey how much storage to reserve.  More importantly, however, it relieves the language implementation from any need to store, track, or dynamically determine objects' types at runtime.  The resulting bare-bytes object representations are, generally speaking, congruent with the underlying machine data model.  This is memory efficient (which was an order of magnitude more important when C was designed than it is now), and CPU efficient.

C code is also amenable to type-based static analysis, which helps detect (some) bugs early, and it supports a wider variety of basic data types than dynamically typed languages such as Python do.

And speaking of Python, do note that even this poster child for dynamically-typed languages now supports data type annotations to provide a few of the advantages that static typing has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this function:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

This function can be typically compiled as an instruction to add two registers and an instruction to return (plus possibly some other instructions needed to implement proper routine interfaces on the platform).

If we did not know what types the arguments were, the compiler would have to generate code to add any possible types of arguments: One-byte integers, two-byte integers, four-byte integers, wider integers, floating-point numbers, strings (for which “adding” them might concatenate the strings), and other support types. Further, it would have to generate code to handle different types of arguments: One might be an integer while the other is a string.

Specifying the types of the arguments makes it possible to generate programs that are tailored to specific tasks with specific data types, and this yields programs that are much smaller and faster.

Answer (score 0):

A variable's type determines the values that the variable can have and the operations that can be performed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Programming languages like C, C++, and Java are statically-typed programming languages. The word "static" here means we need to determine the types at compile time. One way to do that is to just specify the type directly in the code. It makes it easier to implement compilers and for developers to read the code. Another way I know is type inference. So instead of specifying the types in the code, we let the compiler infers the types based on the context. The `any` type in C++ does exactly that.

Different from statically typed languages, dynamically typed languages like Python and Javascript determine the types at runtime. The benefit is that the code is usually more concise and you can do crazy things like conditionally returning different types of data in a function. The downside is that it makes code maintenance significantly harder and easier to produce bugs. That's why we now have Typescript and type annotations in Python to mitigate these problems.