# Do I have to initialize function pointers one by one?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

When I initialize function pointers in one take, like below, it does not work.

```
ptr[3]={add, subtract, multiply};
```

This gives:

> [Error] expected expression before '{' token

However, one-by-one initialization works. Why is this?

```
//array of function pointers

#include<stdio.h>

void add(int a, int b){
    printf("%d\n", a+b);
}


void subtract(int a, int b){
    printf("%d\n", a-b);
}


void multiply(int a, int b){
    printf("%d\n", a*b);
}


int main(){
    
    void (*ptr[3])(int, int);
    
    
    //ptr[3]={add, subtract, multiply};  this initialization does not work
    
    //but this works
    ptr[0]=add;
    ptr[1]=subtract;
    ptr[2]=multiply;
    
    ptr[2](3,5); //15
    
}
```

Comment: `ptr[3]` is an out of bounds access. You then try to assign a list to it, while `ptr[i]` is a single pointer. This is not initialization (because you do it separately from the declaration), and has nothing to do with function pointers (you'd get the same error with an `int` array).

Comment: `void (*ptr[3])(int, int) = {add, subtract, multiply};` initialization like this should work

Comment: can I make declaration and assignment in separate lines for function pointers? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Only the way you did it, by separately assigning to each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the assignment, `ptr[3]={add, subtract, multiply};` the RHS is (correctly) a suitable initializer-list for an array of three function pointers. However, the LHS (`ptr[3]`) is wrong: that's just a single element of an array, and an out-of-bounds element, at that.

Just do the 'assignment' in the declaration, and make it an initialisation:

```c
int main(void)
{
    void (*ptr[3])(int, int) = {add, subtract, multiply}; // this initialization does work
    ptr[2](3, 5); //15
}
```

There is actually nothing special, here, related to the fact that your array's elements are function pointers. No array can be "assigned to" (using the `=` operator) *en bloc*, **at any point other than in its declaration**. In a variable declaration, the use of the `=` token isn't, formally, an assignment operation; it is an initialisation. Useful reading: [Initialization vs Assignment in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35662831/10871073).

Comment: but when I initialize an array of ints, I can do  int arr[3]={4,6,7};  I mean this is not the 3rd element, I am declaring an array of 3 integers. I am not trying to assign the 3rd element.

Comment: @Lyrk Yes, but you can't do `int arr[3];` and then, in a **separate statement**, do `arr[3] = {4,6,7};`. In fact, arrays can ***only*** be intialised with such lists at the point of their declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize during declaration.

```
//array of function pointers

#include<stdio.h>

void add(int a, int b){
    printf("%d\n", a+b);
}


void subtract(int a, int b){
    printf("%d\n", a-b);
}


void multiply(int a, int b){
    printf("%d\n", a*b);
}


int main(){
    
    void (*ptr[3])(int, int) = {add, subtract, multiply};
    
    ptr[2](4,5); //20
    
}
```

Comment: "You need to initialize during declaration." Is this a rule for function pointers only? because I can do declaration and assignment on separate lines in other pointer variables.

Comment: @Lyrk On a separate line that's an assignment, not initialization. The difference matters primarily for arrays, which can't be assigned as a whole in a single line.

Comment: thank you so much. C is overwhelming. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Lyrk Wait until you get to C++. D: